# When to dispose static resources in ASP.NET MVC application life-cycle

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, idisposable

We have an IDisposable resource which is relatively expensive to instantiate although it is stateless and thread safe. So... we decided to wrap using a standard singleton pattern and re-use the single instance for all requests until the app-pool recycles.

With that in mind, we still want to call Dispose() in a deterministic fashion if possible.

The question... What is the appropriate place to dispose such resources, assuming we ever have an opportunity to be graceful in a shut-down scenario? For example...

For context, the application is ASP.NET MVC 4.

```
    protected void Application_Disposed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CleanUpResources();
    }
```

Or...

```
    protected void Application_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CleanUpResources();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way that I know of to hook the application end event is [`IRegisteredObject`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). I don't know about the reliability of `Application_End`.

Answer (score 1):

Is the resource managed or unmanaged? If it is managed, use `Application_End`, otherwise use `Application_Disposed`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx for more info.

Comment: Application_End or Application_End?